# Having a Javascript variable update live

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I am very new Javascript and am messing around trying to make a simple game.  Basically, you can attack or heal and your HP goes up or down accordingly.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myHP=50;
var eHP=50;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function attack()
{
    var dmg=(Math.floor(Math.random()*11));
    var edmg=(Math.floor(Math.random()*11));
    var nHP=myHP - edmg;

    alert("You deal " + dmg + " damage!");
    alert("You are dealt " + edmg + " damage!");
    document.getElementById("hp").innerHTML=nHP;
}
</script>
```

So, I make a paragraph with an id of "hp" and I can see it change when I click the attack button.  However, it always does 50-edmg.  I.e.  I get attacked for 3, my HP is 47.  Next, I get attacked for 2, my HP is 48 and not 45 because it is always subtracting from the base.  How can I make it so that the myHP variable is updated live and therefore always reflects the correct number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never updating the `myHP` variable.  The fix could be as simple as adding:

```
myHP = nHP;
```

as the last line of your last script.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't assigning the new health back to the myHP variable

```
myHP -= edmg
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the health value.

```
myHP = myHP - edmg;
alert("You deal " + dmg + " damage!");
alert("You are dealt " + edmg + " damage!");
document.getElementById("hp").innerHTML= myHP;
```